# Variavel do context processors não funciona com render_to_string

Tags: django, django-templates

Em alguns lugares do meu sistema, eu renderizo uma página com `render_to_string`, pois eu quero renderizar apenas um pequeno conteúdo. Nesses casos eu não recebo minhas variáveis que criei no `context_processors`. Alguém tem uma solução sem ser passar manualmente a variável no dicionário do `render_to_string`? Obrigado.

#### atualização

Depois de uma boa pesquisada descobri que em versões anteriores do Django (encontrei na [versão 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string)) existia um parametro no render_to_string chamada context_instance, onde eu passava o RequestContext e ele carregava já o dicionário com as variáveis do context_processors. Porém por algum motivo foi removida das novas versões. Continuo sem ter uma solução para carregar o `context_processors` no `render_to_string`. Eu realmente preciso da String contendo o HTML carregado com minhas condições que uso de algumas variáveis do `context_processors`. Então ainda meu problema persiste.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que bastaria você fazer:

```
html_body = render_to_string(template_name, context, request=request)
```